# Need to click back arrow twice to go back to previous activity, how to prevent it

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-button, back

I have one activity A and when I click on one button from activity A and come to an another activity B and when I click on back arrow from activity B to go back to A, its comes to the same activity B, so I need to click the back arrow again to go back and when I click on second time, it works.

I have used below approach.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I have also used onKeyDown() approach. But it does not work, its comes to the same activity B, so I need to click the back arrow again to go back to previous activity.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Back arrow, its device back button or your custom arrow button? Can you share code for back click on Activity B?

Comment: Post the code for moving from Activity A to B. You might be starting Activity B 2 times.

Comment: Use the finish() method to finish the current activity when you want to navigate back to the previous activity. This will remove the current activity from the back button stack and ensure that the back button will navigate back to the previous activity.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    // Finish the current activity to navigate back to the previous activity.
    finish();
}

Comment: May be ActivityB is opening twice.

Comment: I am using my custom back arrow. For back click, I am using onBackPressed mentioned in my question

Comment: Sounds strange. Please edit your question and post your manifest.

Comment: Your code for `onBackPressed()` makes no sense and basically does nothing. It just calls the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` in the super class, which calls `finish()` on the current `Activity`. If you remove this code, the effect is the same, as the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` will be called when the BACK button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the parent Activity of your Activity in your Manifest and get lost of the onBackPressed method:

```
<activity
    android:name=".BActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".AActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".AActivity"/>
</activity>
```

That is how it is done.